# Change gedit's overview map width

Tags: gedit

I use gedit as my default editor for non-programming files like taking notes about something and for programmming competitions so editor dosn't bugs me with its suggestions etc. But yesterday while working I hit some key combination by mistake and ended up like this.

Image of gedit edit area to overview map ratio on my system

[image]

Now the overview map is way too large and I could not find anything about overview map. I searched the gedit settings in gsettings and could only find this related to minimap.

```
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor display-overview-map true
```

Does anybody know a way to restore the overview map width to default without reinstalling gedit?

Answer (score 0):

Overview map width is depended on org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor setting right-margin-position (which is by default 80). To make it smaller, lower the value of the setting. Reinstalling gedit would not help, since it doesn't touch the settings.

Comment: I know this is too late, but others might appreciate the info.